# Regex expression to match strings that start with and ends with substrings python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup and converted the resulting soup to string, so currently i have a whole string of information.

within the whole paragraph of string, I want to get all instances of substrings that starts with "price" and ends with "currency". So the price - description within a pattern like this: `"price": 123,"description":"ice-cream","currency":"CAD"`, and this pattern repeats for a number of times in the string paragraph

so something like re.findall("^"price" & "currency"$", string)? I'm not familiar with regex so i can't figure out how to get the correct regex expression.

Below is an example of the string paragraph:

```
{“item”:”xxx”,”price":xxx,”description”:”xxx”,”currency":"USD”,”expiry”:”xxx”},{“item”:”yyy”,”price":yyy,”description”:”yyy”,”currency":"USD”,”expiry”:”yyy”},{“item”:”zzz”,”price":zzz,”description”:”zzz”,”currency":"USD”,”expiry”:”zzz”},....
```

which repeats like 20 times over. Currently, the proposed regex expressions obtains the paragraph from the first occurrence of price to the last occurrence of currency. However, I want to obtain each substring occurrence of "price....currency"

Comment: Do you have an example paragraph?

Comment: `price.*?currency`

Comment: I have added the example paragraph

Comment: You can directly extract the data from the soup object, don't convert it to string - why not recursively extract price and currency keys.

Comment: How can I do that? I have not learnt recursion

Answer (score 0):

Combine
[Pritalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7667848/pritalgo)'s answer with [barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comment and read https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expression-python-examples-set-1/

```
pattern = re.compile(r'"price":\s*(.*?),"')
```

Notice the **non-greedy modifier suffix `?`**, replace the strings before and after `.*?` with the appropriate surrounding strings, if you really want the description included, add the string "currency" as your OP suggests.
`\s*` skips optional whitespace(s). The `()` limits, what gets returned in the `matches` .

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet. I am assuming you want value of currency to be included in the matched string.

```
import re
search_string = """
"price": 123,"description":"ice-cream","currency":"CAD",
"price": 123,"description":"ice-cream","currency":"something", "price": 123,"description":"ice-cream","currency":"something" "price": 123,"description":"ice-cream","currency":"something"
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'"price.*currency".*",?')
matches = pattern.findall(search_string)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I tried it and it is returning me the entire substring from the first occurrence of "price" to the last occurrence of "currency". I want to obtain each substring of "price..... currency" within the string

Comment: @Okay, you just want values of price and currency keys? Like xxx, "USD" etc?

Comment: Yes, I only want the values